# Why is image_hash empty for some ad_creatives? Is it because it is expired?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ads

I ran _">https://graph.facebook.com/act_47121778/adcreatives?access_token=**_**
and got the following results. Why are some creatives returning empty image hash?

```
  {
     "view_tag": "",
     "alt_view_tags": [

     ],
     "creative_id": "6002716206572",
     "type": 1,
     "title": "Grow your fans!",
     "body": "Fan Page Owners! Grow your fanbase. Create quizzes for your page. Win $100 Weekly. Make money with our revenue share program.",
     "image_hash": "6ac30e43f21c8580361de92d3288ed68",
     "link_url": "http://www.facebook.com/quizwriter?sk=app_81434956828",
     "name": "Grow your fans!",
     "run_status": 1,
     "preview_url": "http://www.facebook.com/ads/api/creative_preview.php?cid=6002716206572",
     "count_current_adgroups": 1,
     "id": "6002716206572",
     "image_url": "http://creative.ak.fbcdn.net/v41818/flyers/109/44/1296329249810543669_1_31eb15ed.jpg"
  },
  {
     "view_tag": "",
     "alt_view_tags": [

     ],
     "creative_id": "6002444043572",
     "type": 1,
     "title": "Tennis Champs Social Game",
     "body": "Tennis Champ! Start with 5,000 dollars , beat out other players with your mad tennis skills and become the tennis champ! Socialize!",
     "image_hash": "",
     "link_url": "334886511760",
     "name": "Tennis Champs Social Game",
     "run_status": 1,
     "preview_url": "http://www.facebook.com/ads/api/creative_preview.php?cid=6002444043572",
     "count_current_adgroups": 2,
     "id": "6002444043572"
  },
```